# Ensure that consistency is respected with Kafka, Springboot and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, apache-kafka

Let's assume that I have data in a **Kafka** topic `employee-topic`, 2 **SpringBoot** instances `spring1` and `spring2` of the same application, that store/retreive in/from a **MongoDB**

Let's assume that we have a table `employee` containing two fields: `id` and `amount`

`employee` is populated as the following:

```
+---+---------+
| id|   amount|
+---+---------+
|  1|      200|
+---+---------+
```

In Kafka topic, we have 2 messages, containing 2 amounts: `"amount1": -200` and `"amount1": -100`

Let's say that our spring application will use `spring1` to consume data containing `"amount1"` and `spring2` to consume data containing `"amount2"`

The objective is to update the value in `employee` table.

While updating the value in **MongoDB**, I could have 2 possibilities:

- `spring1` update **before** `spring2`, which means that: `spring1` reads 200, do the sum (-200 + 200) and update the amount becomes 0, `spring1` do the same operation: (-100 + 0) and the amount becomes -100.

```
+---+---------+
| id|   amount|
+---+---------+
|  1|     -100|
+---+---------+
```

- `spring1` update **after** `spring2`, which means that: `spring2` reads 200, do the sum (-100 + 200) and then: `spring1` do the same operation (-200 + (-100)) and the amount becomes -300

```
+---+---------+
| id|   amount|
+---+---------+
|  1|     -300|
+---+---------+
```

This behaviour is random, how can I set a rule, without impacting performance, to set the required behaviour.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's essentially a concurrency issue, so there are a couple options I can suggest:

**Event Sourcing:**

Instead of doing updates, find a way to append a stream of events.

Instead of:

- Current Amount is 200
- Update current amount to current amount -100
- Update current amount to current amount -200
- Get current amount

Do:

- Insert new record with amount of -100
- insert new record with amount of -200
- Starting from the beginning (or a snapshot), aggregate the total amount to get the current amount

**Partition your Topic**

I believe this would best-serve your purposes.

You could pre-assign the database resources to a specific spring instance, based on the id.

Essentially your producer could put messages with odd ids on a topic or partition for spring1 to process, and messages with an even id on a separate topic or partition for spring2 to process. Each spring service would know that the database record to update will not be updated by another spring service, removing the concurrency issue.

**Acquire a Lock**

I can't speak at depth on this, but a last-resort might be having some kind of distributed locking mechanism, like a lock-file, a db flag, a lock-message etc.

Comment: Great, thank you for the advices, I am gonna discuss with my team mates about your proposals !